# Greek letters of attributes are not shown correctly in FME

Tags: fme-form, encoding

I am using FME 2014 in order to manipulate some shape files.
When I load and inspect the content of the shapes file, I get the following problem:

Although all the greek characters of the content is shown correctly (in UTF-8), the titles of each column (seeing in data inspector) are not recognized.
A similar problem I had some time ago with an excel file which had content in greek. In that case also I could see the content of the excel cells but I could see the names of the tabs (sheets).
Back then it was enough to rename the sheets to latin characters but now I don't have this luxury (some hundreds of shape files).

What is the issue here? Is there some internal encoding properties in FME? I see I have the same problem in FME 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted FME support and this is their answer:

"Thank you for contacting Safe Software's support group.  Unfortunately this is a known issue for Shape files created with ArcGIS."

As a workaround I used the transformer: AttributeRenamer. Its a bit of a manual work but if you do it once and all your shape files have the same naming then you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Load your shapefile into Workbench and go to the advanced setting and select Character Encoding and change to **UTF-8**

Here is a quick example using FME Desktop 2015.1.2

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This actually doesn't solve the problem. I tried it but the encoding is already set to utf-8. Actually this is the same parameter I set when I import the shape file.

Comment: The problem is even greater than the above mention. I try to import a shapefile with greek characters and FME can not read it correctly. In the directory field it shows question marks instead of greek characters and its impossible to load it!

Comment: is the shapefile publicly available? It is hard to diagnose without the source file you can submit (workspaces/data) to https://knowledge.safe.com/knowledgeSubmitCase and they can help